# Computation of factorial in SciLab

Tags: factorial, scilab

This Scilab function is supposed to compute the factorial of n. But it gives an error stated below:

```
function fac(n)
   if (n<=0) then n = 1
   else 
       n =  n* fac(n-1)     
   end
endfunction
```

The errors are stated here :

```
-->fac(23)

 !--error 44 
Wrong argument #2.
at line       5 of function fac called by :  
at line       5 of function fac called by :  
at line       5 of function fac called by :  
at line       5 of function fac called by :  
at line       5 of function fac called by :  
at line       5 of function fac called by :  
at line       5 of function fac called by :  
at line       5 of function fac called by :  
at line       5 of function fac called by :  
at line       5 of function fac called by :  
at line       5 of function fac called by :  
at line       5 of function fac called by :  
at line       5 of function fac called by :  
at line       5 of function fac called by :  
at line       5 of function fac called by :  
at line       5 of function fac called by :  
at line       5 of function fac called by :  
at line       5 of function fac called by :  
at line       5 of function fac called by :  
at line       5 of function fac called by :  
at line       5 of function fac called by :  
at line       5 of function fac called by :  
at line       5 of function fac called by :  
fac(23)
```

Comment: Have you tried to output the value of ``n'' every time you call fac. What is the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the return value `n =` in the very first line just after `function`, it will never return anything otherwise

```
function n = fac(n)

   if (n<=0) then n = 1
   else 
       n =  n* fac(n-1)
   end

endfunction
```

Comment: Yup  , I forgot to transfer it to n. Nice eye catch!

Comment: Haha, never too late to answer .